# MYSQL left join function results missing rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables. 
A with item, (inventory master list)
B with item, date, and sales   (sales sheet)

I have:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT A.item, sum(B.qty) \
    FROM A \
    LEFT JOIN sales on A.item = B.item \
    WHERE B.date BETWEEN %s AND %s\
    GROUP BY A.item", (gr2014start, gr2014end))
```

This doesn't list all items in A
I understand that under the selected date range, some of the item in A didn't have any sales on B so it doesn't exist. 
Is there a way I can list them as zero with join function ?

I had this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT A.item, \
    (SELECT COALESCE(sum(qty),0) From B \
    WHERE (A.item = B.item) \
    AND (B.date BETWEEN %s AND %s)) as 'Qty' \
    FROM A", (gr2014start, gr2014end))
```

This works. But somehow this one is very slow (3 or 4 times slower than the incomplete join function on top)

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a `LEFT JOIN`, if there's no matching row in table `B`, those columns will be `NULL`, so `B.date BETWEEN %s AND %s` will always be false.

Put the restrictions on `B.date` in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause: `LEFT JOIN sales AS B ON A.item = B.item AND B.date BETWEEN %s AND %s`. This is the exception to the general rule that `ON` clauses should only contain comparisons between the tables being joined.

Comment: thanks @Barmar. Somehow the 1) doesn't work in this case maybe because some of the items in a doesn't exist in b. With 1) it still doesn't return a full list same length as A.  2) works perfectly

Comment: 1) should work just as well. Do you have additional tests in your `WHERE` clause that you didn't show in the question? Make sure you put parentheses around the `OR` expression.

Comment: I just tested. List a.item includes some item that b.item doesn't have. When I do: LEFT JOIN a on a.item = b.item AND b.date BETWEEN %s AND %s. Those item shows. ------------------------ If I do:  LEFT JOIN a on a.item = b.item WHERE b.date IS NULL OR b.date BETWEEN %s AND %s. Those doesn't show in the result

Comment: You're right. When using the `OR` clause, it leaves out rows in A that have matches in B, but all the matches are outside the date range. So there's no `NULL` row to match the `B.date IS NULL` test.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a `left join` some of the dates from B will be NULL. If you want all the results in the date range AND results with no associated record in B, you need to account for that:

```
WHERE B.date IS NULL OR B.date BETWEEN %s AND %s
```

Comment: See the comments below my answer. This won't work if all the matching rows are outside the date range.